# Error when retrieving nested list values in python

Tags: python

I have this as my code right now

`main.py`:

```py
help = ["/help", ["This returns a list of all commands"]]
color = ["/color", ["This changes the color of the console"]]
cmds = [help, color]

def getHelp(cmd:str=None):
  if not cmd:
    for index, c in enumerate(cmds):
      for i, help in enumerate(c):
        print(help+":", c[1])
    return 
  print("Retrieving command")
  for c in cmds:
    for help in c:
      if c == cmd[1]:
        print(console_color+help)
      else:
        continue
```

It returns the first list, but not the second one.
Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 93, in <module>
    login()
  File "main.py", line 63, in login
    main()
  File "main.py", line 51, in main
    getHelp()
  File "main.py", line 34, in getHelp
    print(help+":", c[1])
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hallo and welcome to StackOverflow. can you provide more details on how you call the function.
What do expect `if not cmd` this line to do?

Comment: 2nd your error tells you that you try to join a list+a string, in that print statement. You have to at least use str(thelist) for it to work on a minimal level.

Comment: @Daraan I tried `print(str(help)+":", str(c[1]))` and it prints the description of the command twice
`/help: ['This returns a list of all commands']
['This returns a list of all commands']: ['This returns a list of all commands']
/color: ['This changes the color of the console']
['This changes the color of the console']: ['This changes the color of the console']`

Comment: @Daraan If you take the time to look at the function arguments, you can see the `str` argument named `cmd` that defaults to None. When this function is called, If there is no `cmd` passed, it shows all commands inside the `cmds` list.

Comment: I miss interpreted your code a bit it's not easy to follow within a glance. Consider using a dictionary instead of lists. You're using the variable name help twice. So help will not necessarily be the list declared on top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a fix:

```py
def getHelp(cmd:str=None):
  ct = 0
  if not cmd:
    for c in cmds:
      for help in c:
        ct += 1
        if ct % 2 == 0: # prevents printing the command and desc twice
          continue
        elif ct == len(cmds):
          return
        print(str(help)+":", str(c[1]).strip('[\']')) # removes the brackets and quotes
```

If the count is a multiple of 2, it is skipped (to prevent printing twice). If the count is equal to the amount of commands, the iteration is stopped.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In Line 34, you are concatenating the list to the str (":").

You can replace line 34 with any of the following two solutions to avoid the error:

1. `print(help,":", c[1])`
2. `print(str(help)+":", c[1])`